# Safeguarding against SQL injections in vba (using an oracle db and ADODB)

Tags: vba, oracle, adodb

I have recently created an excel sheet that the HR department can use as an interface to write and read from my db in (by me) controlled manner. Basically its just a bunch of VBA buttons that read to / write from certain tables in excel.

I would like to safeguard against SQL injections, but I'm not sure what I need to do in order to achieve that. I have heard that prepared statements are a way to solve that problem, should I use them? If yes, could you guys provide a link that explains how to do that? All I find is some Java JDBC stuff :/.

Also I've found people using constructs like

```
Replace(t.DataBodyRange(1, x), "'", " ")
```

to eliminate characters that are used to write SQL injections. Does that solution work?

Are there any other (better) ways of doing it?

Comment: The conventional and probably best way to avoid SQL injection is to use parameterized queries (probably what you mean by prepared statements).  Google for "ADO parameterized queries" and you'll find lots of resources, e.g. https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx

Comment: Thx, yes the problem with me not finding anything when googling seems to be that for some reason I thought it was named prepared statement instead of parameterized query